# jOOQ - MySQL multiple row INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE using VALUES() function

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

Does jOOQ have support for the VALUES() function on for use in INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

If not, any suggestions on how to do it instead? (For a lot of rows)

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: please see http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using PostgreSQL specific syntax in jOOQ's API

jOOQ doesn't have this MySQL specific `VALUES()` support in the API, but you can use the PostgreSQL specific equivalent via `DSL.excluded()` starting from jOOQ 3.17. [This is documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key-excluded/).

A statement like this:

```java
insertInto(AUTHOR, AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
   .values(3, "X")
   .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
   .set(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, excluded(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME))
   .execute();
```

Will be translated to this MySQL equivalent statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (ID, LAST_NAME)
VALUES (
  3, 
  'X'
)
AS t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  AUTHOR.LAST_NAME = t.LAST_NAME
```

Or on older versions of MySQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO AUTHOR (ID, LAST_NAME)
VALUES (
  3, 
  'X'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  AUTHOR.LAST_NAME = VALUES(LAST_NAME)
```

Note that `VALUES(column_name)` has been deprecated with more recent versions of MySQL, and as such shouldn't be used anymore.

[See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77727568/521799).

#### Historic answer:

As of jOOQ 3.8, there's no such support and there's currently no support planned to be added. You can easily get that working on your side using plain SQL, though:

```java
public static <T> Field<T> values(Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field("values({0})", field.getDataType(), field);
}
```

For more information about "plain SQL" in jOOQ, see:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2021, you can use Jooq's [InsertOnConflictWhereStep](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/InsertOnConflictWhereStep.html).

Here is a sample of what this could look like (in Kotlin):

```
fun saveOrUpdate(items: Iterable<SomeClass>) {
    dsl.insertInto(
        TABLE,
        TABLE.FIELD1,
        TABLE.FIELD2,
    ).apply {
        items.forEach { item ->
            values(
                item.field1,
                item.field2
            )
                .onConflict(
                    TABLE.FIELD1
                )
                .doUpdate()
                .set(TABLE.FIELD2, item.field2)
                .set(TABLE.UPDATED_AT, currentOffsetDateTime())
        }
    }
        .execute()
}
```