# How to specifiy row alias in jOOQ when inserting with VALUES()

Tags: mysql, jooq

In MySQL 8 a row alias can be specified when inserting values to reference it in an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement as following:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, col1, col2) 
VALUES(123, 'foo', 'bar'), (321, 'bar', 'baz') as new_row
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = new_row.col1, col2 = new_row.col2
```

This is replacing the old `VALUES()` function, see https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13325

Unfortunately I am not able to write this query in jOOQ since the `InsertValuesStep` does not allow me to specify an alias. Is there any other possibility to add this alias, for example by using the plain SQL DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't support this particular MySQL specific syntax via API, but you can use the [PostgreSQL specific `EXCLUDED` pseudo table](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-conflict-excluded/) for this. [This usage is now documented in the manual as well](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key-excluded/), see [#15999](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15999). So, assuming you're using at least jOOQ 3.17, write:

```java
ctx.insertInto(FOO)
   .columns(FOO.ID, FOO.COL1, FOO.COL2)
   .values(123, "foo", "bar")
   .values(321, "bar", "baz")
   .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
   .set(FOO.COL1, excluded(FOO.COL1))
   .set(FOO.COL2, excluded(FOO.COL2))
   .execute();
```

With this approach, you cannot give your `VALUES()` clause an explicit name, but this isn't really necessary anyway.

Comment: So to achieve the same result instead of setting col1 and col2 I would have to exclude id, correct? 

I was already able to set the values as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793406/jooq-mysql-multiple-row-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-using-values-funct, however I get a deprecation warning from mysql, thats why I wanted to change it.

Comment: @m-kay: No, not "to exclude it". You have to use the PostgreSQL style `EXCLUDED` pseudo table, which is then translated by jOOQ to MySQL specific syntax. Excluded here means that the *row* has been excluded from the `INSERT` part of the statement, so it is available to the `UPDATE` part of the statement. A bit weird, but that's how it's called in PostgreSQL. Just replace `VALUES(column)` by `EXCLUDED.column` in your thinking, the semantics is equivalent.